# Чтение кирилицы с файла C#

Tags: c#, файлы

Нужно считать файл в которм есть символы кирилицы, при выводе на екран все клирические символы отображаються знаками вопроса.
Вот как я читаю текст из файла:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = @"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\words\worxds.txt";

            using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                // преобразуем строку в байты
                byte[] array = new byte[fstream.Length];
                // считываем данные
                fstream.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
                // декодируем байты в строку
                string textFromFile = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array);
                Console.WriteLine($"Текст из файла: {textFromFile}");
            }

        }
```

Есть ли способ, корректно отобращить кирилицу после чтения в консоле?

Comment: Файл в какой кодировке? Консоль выводит текст `Текст из файла` на русском?

Comment: Вместо символов кирилицы выводяться знаки вопроса, кодирока ANSI

Comment: Какая именно ANSI? 1251? Например, `Console.WriteLine($"Текст из файла: {File.ReadAllText("path", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))}");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Unicode. Если вы кодируете что-либо, кроме английского (американского) языка, то *всегда* используйте Unicode.

Вы, конечно, можете использовать и 1251 (ASCII 7-битная, +1 бит под русские символы), но она используется только в текстах на русском, а в Unicode можно вставить любые символы в 1-м тексте.

```cs
var text = File.ReadAllText("path/to/file", Encoding.Unicode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно изменить кодировку файла на UTF-8.

Comment: если уже и использовать 8-битные кодировки, то 1251.